# AWS amplify install web dependencies with NPM instead of Yarn

Tags: aws-amplify

How can I change the Package Manager prior to the build in my AWS Amplify?

I have been googling around but it seems like nobody had a similar need. In the AWS dashboard have not found any option either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS-Amplify dashboard, on the left pane, go to "Build Settings" and modify the YAML file line:

[image]

```
yarn install
```

for

```
npm install
```